# Code is correct, teacher approved, but it's not working. How do I make it run? (Python random module)

Tags: python, random, module, python-module

This code is absolutely, 100% correct. It works on the teacher's computer and runs perfectly, but on mine it does not. I have no clue why that would be. The issue is the same on Mac and Windows (someone else had the same problem). I have Windows 8.1, if that's relevant, and I save all of my python files in Documents. I have Python 3.5, and I have the same issues in the Shell and in the command window.

It does work to a point - it prints the student names it's supposed to, but then it prints the ending message twice and freaks out.

I've imported the turtle module before with 0 issues. I haven't imported anything other than it and random, so I'm not sure if it's JUST random or if it's other modules too.

Here's the code. It's to randomly pick students for activities:

```
def addlist():
    maxLengthList = int(input("How many students?"))
    turtle.title("Class Chooser")
    while len(kids) < maxLengthList:
        name = turtle.textinput("Students", "Enter a name")
        kids.append(name)
    nextturn()

def nextturn():
    turn = random.choice(kids)
    kids.remove(turn)
    print("Next " + turn)
    again=len(kids)
    while again>0:
        nextturn()
        again=again-1
    else:
        print("Have a nice day!")

import random
import turtle
kids = []
addlist()
```

And here's the error message. I've inputted lucy, alex, jake, and bro for the students' names:

```
How many students?4
Next lucy
Next alex
Next jake
Next bro
Have a nice day!
Have a nice day!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Seren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\random.py", line 253, in choice
    i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
  File "C:\Users\Seren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\random.py", line 230, in _randbelow
    r = getrandbits(k)          # 0 <= r < 2**k
ValueError: number of bits must be greater than zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Seren\Documents\~School~\Computer Programming\isolated code ex.py", line 24, in <module>
    addlist()
  File "C:\Users\Seren\Documents\~School~\Computer Programming\isolated code ex.py", line 7, in addlist
    nextturn()
  File "C:\Users\Seren\Documents\~School~\Computer Programming\isolated code ex.py", line 16, in nextturn
    nextturn()
  File "C:\Users\Seren\Documents\~School~\Computer Programming\isolated code ex.py", line 16, in nextturn
    nextturn()
  File "C:\Users\Seren\Documents\~School~\Computer Programming\isolated code ex.py", line 10, in nextturn
    turn = random.choice(kids)
  File "C:\Users\Seren\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\random.py", line 255, in choice
    raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence')
IndexError: Cannot choose from an empty sequence
```

Do any of you have a fix for this? If I can't import random properly, my assignments will be nearly impossible to do.

EDIT: I think it's a problem with my computer, or my operating system, or the version of python I've downloaded. Anything outside the code that would cause the random module to go weird.

UPDATE: If I put quit() after print("Have a nice day!"), no error message pops up and the program seems to run as intended. I'm not sure if this is so much a solution as a band-aid, though.

Comment: Your code seems backwards, with imports at the bottom and a function being called before it's defined.

Comment: You have a call to `nextturn()` which shouldn't work where it is (before it is defined), but calling `nextturn` before you call `addlist` would certainly produce this error.

Comment: Guys, as odd as it might seem, the problem is not `nextturn` being called before its definition (maybe it's was just an identation error when he psted the code here). The error is that `kids` is an empty sequence when `random.choice(kids)` is called.

Comment: For the teacher's computer, the program skips over functions entirely before going back up to them. It doesn't matter where they are. The weird nextturn() placement was me copying the code in wrong.

Comment: Replace the while loop by an if statement and you will be set. The reason of this weird behavior is the recursion and the while loop in the same function.

Comment: If "This code is absolutely, 100% correct" (even in the face of such oddities), I don't know what there is for us to do.

Comment: Kids shouldn't be an empty sequence...random.choice(kids) is called after appending all of the inputted names, or it should be. How would I fix that?

Replacing with if makes it go really weird. No matter how many names I want, I can only enter 1. It'll print "Next [name]", but then it prints a 0 and asks for another input.

Comment: @Rodolfo this doesn't seem to be this since the `again` variable is exactly the length of the global `kids`. If it entered the loop, it should necessarily not be empty.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 It worked on my teacher's computer. That's all I know. I added it to the post, but I'm mainly wondering if there's an issue with my operating system, the module, python 3.5, whatever that would cause random to freak out.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti You would be correct if he had done `while kids`; however, again does not update as the length of the kid changes on the recursive function.

Comment: Are your python versions the same as your teacher? Is the imports modules the same version as your teacher? Have you tried to clean install of Python?

Comment: @Seren Rodolfo is correct, the `while` is definitely the problem. However, it appears to work when the number of students is 1 or 2. Did your teacher use one of those two numbers?

Comment: @MooingRawr Should be. She sent us links to the exact version we should have. I wouldn't know about the modules...if it's the same version of Python, would it always be the same modules? I have not tried to clean install, although I do remember having problems with the initial download. I thought I'd gotten rid of everything before installing again, but I could try that.

Comment: @dkasak I think she might've only done 2. Although, it still prints "Have a nice day!" twice for some reason. Once reaching the end of the function, it should go back out, find nothing, then stop, right? Would the problem be fixed if I put the while loop back into the main code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this weird behavior is the use of recursion and a while loop to call the same function.

There are many ways to solve this; however, I recommend to get rid of the while loop entirely as it is confusing:

```
def addlist():
    maxLengthList = int(input("How many students?"))
    turtle.title("Class Chooser")
    while len(kids) < maxLengthList:
        name = turtle.textinput("Students", "Enter a name")
        kids.append(name)
    nextturn()

def nextturn():
    turn = random.choice(kids)
    kids.remove(turn)
    print("Next " + turn)
    again=len(kids)
    if again>0:
        nextturn()
        again=again-1
    else:
        print("Have a nice day!")

import random
import turtle
kids = []
addlist()
```

I would also standarize the code a bit, to make it more readable:

```
import random
import turtle
kids = []
def addlist():
    maxLengthList = int(input("How many students?"))
    turtle.title("Class Chooser")
    while len(kids) < maxLengthList:
        name = turtle.textinput("Students", "Enter a name")
        kids.append(name)
    nextturn()

def nextturn():
    turn = random.choice(kids)
    kids.remove(turn)
    print("Next " + turn)
    if kids:
        nextturn()
    else:
        print("Have a nice day!")

addlist()
```

**Update:**

This is the long explanation of what your code was doing:

Suppose you have a list with `[ann, bob, charlie]`.

- On Call #1 to `nextturn`: you remove a kid so the variables are like this: (global kids=['ann', 'bob'], local again=2) before entering the loop.
- On Call #2 to `nextturn` your variables are like this before entering the loop(global kids=[ann], local again=1)
- On Call #3 it will be (global kids=[empty], local again=0) before (not) entering the loop. This will simply print "Have a nice day" and exit successfully

Call 3 will end leaving the list empty. BUT Call 1 and 2 are still active.
After the first iteration of the while loop on Call #2 the local variable `again` is 0, so it prints "Have a nice day" (again) and exits.

But then in Call 1: the local variable `again` is 1, which means the loop will execute again on an empty list!!!.

And that caused the problem.

Comment: This is correct, however I think the intention is to output "Have a nice day!" for each of the students, so the `print` should probably not be inside the `else`.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! You've saved my life. Could you please explain exactly why the while loop didn't work? Is it because it would go back to the top of the function before subtracting 1 from again, or because I was going to the same function from within it in the first place? I should add that the clunkiness is probably because this is an intro class, so we're forcing several concepts into this one piece of code. No clue what the while loop was about though.

Comment: @Seren I  updated the answer with an explanation. I will try to update it again if you have any questions.

Comment: @Seren Imagine what happens when `kids` initially has, say, five items and you enter the call of `nextturn` where the final item of `kids` gets popped. After that call is done, you will return to the `while` loop in the caller where `again == 1` and you will do `again -= 1` and exit the loop. However, then you'll return to the `while` of the next caller down the stack and there `again == 2` which will get decreased to 1, which is still larger than 0, so you will not exit the loop but call `nextturn` again. But the `kids` list is empty by now, which is causing the error.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use the `random.randint(0,x)` to define what student you want, e.g.

```
print(students[random.randint(0,3)]
```

Not sure if this helps, another suggestion may be trying a simpler `print(random.randint(1,4)` in another project just to see if it is working?

(Also you should probably put the `import random` stuff at the very front.

Comment: We haven't gotten to that in our class yet, but thank you anyway! So I've heard for the import random, ha ha. She just put it at the bottom to show that you could and that functions are ignored by the program until called.

Comment: No, it's a very informal class. Pretty much just for fun, and very much beginner-level, although I am hoping to do more coding outside of it once I've got a decent foundation.

Comment: @Seren Awesome, coding is really fun, I'm taking. It as and Betec alongside maths + physics. *Sigh*. Glad to hear that there is other enthusiastic coders like me who have the bravery to ask for help!